# Why can't I initialize storage array right away?

Tags: solidity, storage

Why can't I initialize storage arrays when declaring them rather than initializing them in function or constructor?

example:
this does not work, it amounts to [0, 0, 0, 0]

```
contract Example {
   uint256[4] array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
   ...
   constructor () {}
}
```

this does work

```
contract Example {
   uint256[4] array;
   ...
   constructor () {
      array[0] = [1];
      array[1] = [2];
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the storage array like state variable.

Your code works!

To see the values inside your array you can add this function in your contract:

```
function getArray(uint index) external view returns(uint256){
       return array[index];
}
```

Now, you must to compile the contract, and put the position index of array that you want the value and it will return the value.

**UPDATED ANSWER**:
For initialize state variable, you must use the following statement:

```
uint256[4] array = [[VALUE_INDEX_0], [VALUE_INDEX_1], [VALUE_INDEX_2], [VALUE_INDEX_3]];
```

You must to use only the statement above if you want to initialize and array like state variable. But in a function or constructor you can the statement above or you can access at single index of array and pass it the value.
Ex.:

```
array[0] = 10;
array[1] = 20;
```

Comment: I'm not sure your example of initializing it in storage works, could you maybe write an example of initializing it with real values?

Comment: This is an example of initializing values in storage array variable: uint256[4] array = [0, 1, 2, 3];

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't work.

Comment: You must to insert the instruction below the keyword contract. And to retrieve the array values you can use the function that I wrote above. I tried and it works. Can you expalin better what is the problem?

Comment: Yes of course...
initializing it like you've mentioned:
uint256[4] array = [[VALUE_INDEX_0], [VALUE_INDEX_1], [VALUE_INDEX_2], [VALUE_INDEX_3]];
simply doesnt work and initializes it to [0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Did you see the array values using the function that I declared above?

Comment: Yes of course it returns 0

Comment: Stupid recommendation: If you execut getArray() function and you try to put like index 0. You should see this result: 0: uint256: 1. The result is the last character reading from left to right. In this case is 1.

Comment: Im using hardhat, there it compiles to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine!
I added a view function `getArray()` to get your storage array.

```
contract Example {
   uint256[4] array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

   constructor () {}

    function getArray() external view returns(uint256[4] memory) {
       return array;
   }
}
```